# how can i detect data from an external file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I usually use "getElementById()" to detect internal file data . I tried this to detect data from an external file but its not work :

```
<script>
var outterPage ="dom1.html";
var temp=outterPage.getElementById("abc").innerHTML;
</script>
```

what can i do to detect data from external file ?

Comment: what do you mean by "internal" and "external" ? getElementById returns you a DOM element by id.

Comment: Is the page dom1.html on the same domain?

Comment: @Jack Zelig same domain and the same folder

Alp i mean : internal : same file . external : another file .

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments is this what your're looking for? Are you trying to update your page with the data from the other page?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery function `$.get` to read the contents of a URL into a variable. Then you can parse that into a DOM element to find parts of it.

```
$.get("dom1.html", function(data) {
    var temp = $("<div>", { html: data }).find("#abc").html();
    // do something with temp
});
```

You can also specify the ID in the URL argument to `$.get`, so jQuery will just return the contents of that part of the page.

```
$.get("dom1.html #abc", function(temp) {
    // do something with temp
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the external file into a dom element and then get its value.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#holder").load("dom1.html");
var temp=$("#holder").find("#abc").innerHTML;
});
</script>
```

Comment: $() : what is this mean ?

Comment: $() is short hand for $(document). Changed it in the code for avoiding confusion.

Comment: @anas That's basic jQuery syntax. You used the jquery tag, don't you know jquery?

Comment: @Barmar: It's my fault. I provided a jquery solution without knowing his competence with the language.

Comment: @DinoMyte No, it seems like it's his fault for tagging the question with jquery when he has no idea how to use it.